# Изоляция кода в Net Core 3.0+

Tags: .net, .net-core

Вычитал, что из `.Net Core` 3.0+ выпилили `AppDomain'ы`.

Ввели `AssemblyLoadContext`, но как я понимаю, он годится только для сценариев, когда нужно иметь возможность выгрузить ненужные сборки без пересоздания `AppDomain`.

А как теперь быть с непроверенным кодом? Раньше его можно было запустить в отдельном `AppDomain` и через какую-то оболочку дергать методы, а потом при необходимости прибить, без завершения работы программы.

Использовать `IPC`? Ну это так себе, если приложение работает через плагины + удобного WCF'а не завезли в .NET Core.

Какие способы можно использовать для изоляции непроверенного кода в .NET CORE 3.0?

Comment: можно запускать child process и убивать его. В инете есть удобные либы которые позволяют таску или поток запустить в отдельном процессе

Comment: @SultanovShamil ну... что-то я не представляю, как можно взаимодействовать с плагином, который находится в другом процессе и должен какой-то элемент интерфейса нарисовать в UI.